# Why does SqlAlchemy not close database connections

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid, pymssql

I have a `pyramid==1.10.4`, `SQLAlchemy==1.3.19` and `pymssql==2.2.1` setup to use the default [QueuePool](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html?highlight=max_overflow#sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool.__init__) with `{pool_size: 5, max_overflow: 40, pool_recycle: 3600 }` but it does not close connections when it opens connections in excess of the configured `pool_size`. For example, at one point it opened 14 connections and some of the connections have been idle for over 8 hours and not closed.

```
sqlalchemy.convert_unicode = true
sqlalchemy.max_overflow = 10
sqlalchemy.pool_recycle = 3600
sqlalchemy.pool_size = 5
sqlalchemy.strategy = plain
sqlalchemy.url = mssql+pymssql://username:password@db_host/db?login_timeout=2&timeout=5
```

```
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, DateTime, String, Boolean, Text, Float
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())

settings = config.get_settings()
engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    user_id = Column('UserId', Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column('FirstName', Unicode(50), nullable=False)

class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User

user = DBSession.query(User).filter_by(user_id=200).first()
schema = UserSchema(session=DBSession)
myuser = schema.dump(user)

with DBSession.begin():
   BSession.add(myuser)

query = DBSession.query(User).filter_by(user_id=200).first()


# this is a pyramid hook that is fired one every http response
# https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/events.html#pyramid.events.NewResponse
config.add_subscriber(
   close_db_session,
   'pyramid.events.NewResponse'
)

def close_db_session(event=None):
    DBSession.close()
```

My expectation is that the pool will keep a max of 5 connections in the pool and can request more connections up to the `max_overflow` limit but any connections checked out in excess of the `pool_size` will be closed immediately when returned to the pool.

But I am not seeing the connections closing. I even set the `poos_size` to 1 to experiment with but it still keeps all the connections open and doing nothing.

Comment: Does your code close the sessions?  The code in the question shows a session accessed via a context manager (ok, `close()` is called automatically) but another which is called without being closed.  If sessions aren't closed then connections aren't released.

Comment: Ah yeah, I updated the code to show that I close the db session every time a pyramid http response is generated `pyramid.events.NewResponse`.